# Why we have to mention generic type parameter before the method return type?

Tags: java, generics

Here on this [page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html), it has the below code example to introduce the generic methods?

```
public static <K, V> boolean compare(Pair<K, V> p1, Pair<K, V> p2) {
    return p1.getKey().equals(p2.getKey()) &&
           p1.getValue().equals(p2.getValue());
}
```

1. I have a question on why we need to mention the generics before the 'boolean' here? this method is just returning boolean type.. When i removed the `<K, V>` compiler throws error saying `cannot make a static reference to the non-static type K`.

   ```
   public void setValue(V value) {
       this.value = value;
   }
   ```
2. On the same link, we have the above method then why don't we have here the generic type parameter mentioned as `<V>`?

**EDIT:** Posting the completed code here for better understanding of my question:

Util.Java

```
public class Util {
    // Generic static method
    public static <K, V> boolean compare(Pair<K, V> p1, Pair<K, V> p2) {
        return p1.getKey().equals(p2.getKey()) &&
               p1.getValue().equals(p2.getValue());
    }
}
```

Pair.Java

```
public class Pair<K, V> {

    private K key;
    private V value;

    // Generic constructor
    public Pair(K key, V value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    // Generic methods
    public void setKey(K key) { this.key = key; }
    public void setValue(V value) { this.value = value; }
    public K getKey()   { return key; }
    public V getValue() { return value; }
}
```

Comment: It's static.
See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409100/how-to-make-a-java-generic-method-static

Comment: @user2588666: And the reverse of this question is here: [Static method in a generic class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936377/static-method-in-a-generic-class)

Comment: I can't reproduce your error massage. If I remove `<K,V>` from method I get `error: cannot find symbol public static  boolean compare(Pair<**K**, V> p1, Pair<K, V> p2) { symbol:   class K,  location: class Util`. Consider posting [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which will let us reproduce your actual problem. Anyway to be short, if you want to use some generic type in method, but you didn't declare it in class itself via `class YourClass<K,V>` you can do it in method. You need to declare it right before its return type, because return type can also use generic type you declared.

Comment: @Pshemo I did not want the question to be too long and boring so did not post the full code here instead mentioned the link.

Comment: It is more important for question to be accurate than not-boring. No one wants you to paste million lines of code, just create some simple example which will let us reproduce your error/problem.

Comment: @Pshemo Thanks. I just updated the question with the completed code. Now i guess you will create the same error as mine :)

Answer (score 3):

If the class does not declare a generic type, the method will not know about the type you are requesting. This is usually the case with static, since these methods are not part of an instance of a class.

The scope of a generic parameter on a class only falls within the instance methods and fields. Static methods must declare their own type parameter for only its scope.

#### From [The Java™ Tutorials: Generic Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html)

> Generic methods are methods that introduce their own type parameters. This is similar to declaring a generic type, but the type parameter's scope is limited to the method where it is declared. Static and non-static generic methods are allowed, as well as generic class constructors.

It appears that your example is from this page, you have all the information you need on that page. If you need to explore more information about Generics, continue on with your tutorial. :-)

For your second question, the `setValue()` method is a member of the `Pair` class, which provides both the `K` and `V` type parameters:

```
public class Pair<K, V> {
    private V value;
    public void setValue(V value) { this.value = value; }
    public V getValue() { return value; }
}
```

`V` is declared within the scope of the instance.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of declaring and using generic type parameters in Java.

1. Like the `compare` method, you can declare type parameters on the method itself.  These are declared before the return type, and they can be used throughout the method.
2. Like the `setValue` method, type parameters not declared on the method must be declared somewhere else -- on the class declaration itself.  In the `setValue` method's class, you see something like this:

Pair:

```
public class Pair<K, V> {
```

This is where class-scope generic type parameters are declared.  They are in scope throughout the class, including the `setValue` method.

The exception is that such class-level type parameters are not in scope on `static` methods, so they must be declared on a `static` method to be in scope.  Note that they would be different type parameters that those declared on the class anyway.

Comment: @Pshemo Oops.  It was indented, but that counts towards the markdown list.  Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

> Why we have to mention generic type parameter before the method return type?

Because the return type might use one of the generic types, and because the method is static so it doesn't 'see' the generic types of the containing class.

> On the same link, we have the above method then why don't we have here the generic type parameter mentioned as ?

Because it must be contained in a generic class.

Answer (score 0):

Your question relates to *method* generic parameters, which are declared *before* the return type - which is necessary because the return type could be, and often is, based on the generic type.

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention the generic types because otherwise `K` and `V` will each be interpreted as a concrete `class` or `interface`. The program won't compile because `K` and `V` can't be found. Adding the generics before the method tells the compiler that these classes are generics. If they cannot be inferred by the types of the input when it is called you will need to mention it like so :

```
Foo.<String>createFoo();
```

The fact that you are(n't) returning an object derived from the generics is not the entire reason for these requirements.