# Cannot find symbol clone() in interface Cloneable

Tags: java

I am trying to clone a list of Cloneables:

```
public static <T extends Cloneable> List<T> cloneList(List<T> list)
{
    List<T> out = new ArrayList<T>();
    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
    {
        out.add((T)((T)list.get(i)).clone());
    }
    return out;
}
```

which throws the error:

```
Helpers.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
            out.add((T)((T)list.get(i)).clone());
                                       ^
  symbol:   method clone()
  location: interface Cloneable
```

Why is that; isn't `clone()` the single method the `Cloneable` interface is all about?

Comment: Did you look at the Javadoc of Cloneable?

Comment: @KarthikR The list should be able to contain any object type that implements the Cloneable interface. I think this is called "generics"...

Comment: @KarthikR I made the method a static generic method as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409100/how-to-make-a-java-generic-method-static

Comment: Didn't note that it's a compilation error. Apologies. Will let u know.

Answer (score 2):

clone() is protected by default , could you please override it as public

Answer (score 1):

`Cloneable` is a [marker](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/01/what-is-marker-interfaces-in-java-and.html) interface, clone() method is in Object class, So you should override clone() method in your class as per your requirement, and you also have to implement Cloneable interface to tell JVM that the object is cloneable. Cloneable interface works like Serializable interface which is for serialization.

Comment: I want the method to consume ANY type that implements `Cloneable` interface - not necessarily a class I wrote by myself.

Comment: @Alexander, I got your point, but the fact is to make a class Cloneable, there are two conditions, one is that Class must implement Cloneable interface and second point is that the class must override clone() method and make it as public,

Comment: I don't have a class, I only have a static method that should clone a list of cloneables. The cloneable should bring a way to clone it, and I just try to clone a list of these.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `Cloneable` and override `clone()` to use it (make it `public`, it's `protected` in the `Object` class).