# java generic declaration defaulting to type object when calling it via a builder method

Tags: java, generics

I have a series of Data Transport Objects, DTO. They have a few elements that are common to each different DTO. One element is a collection of the DTO, because we can have a list, or series of these DTO's to process at a time. I've used generics so Spring can handle the different DTOs and pass up to the UI. Here are some excerpts from my GenericListDTO() class.

```
 @XmlElement
    @NotNull
    private Collection<DTO> dataList;
    @XmlElement
    private int totObjs;
```

My DTO builder is defined like this:

```
public static <DTO> GenericListDTOBuilder<DTO> builder() { 
   return new GenericListDTOBuilder<>(); 
}
```

Here is the builder class defined inside my GenericList Class.

```
public static class GenericListDTOBuilder<DTO> {
        private Collection<DTO> dataList;

        public GenericListDTOBuilder<DTO> data(@NotNull Collection<DTO> data) {
            this.dataList = dataList;
            return this;
        }

        private int total;
        
        public GenericListDTOBuilder<DTO> total(int total) {
            this.total = total;
            return this;
        }

        public GenericListDTO<DTO> build() {
            return new GenericListDTO<>(this.data, this.total, this.validUntil);
        }

        
        }

    }
```

Later in the class I have this constructor.

```
@NotNull
    public static <DTO> GenericListDTO<DTO> just(@NotNull Collection<DTO> dataList) {
        
        return  builder().dataList(dataList).total(dataList.size()).build();
    }
```

Intellij at the .dataList(dataList) portion gives this error, "Required type: Collection Provided:Collection.

I don't understand why it's giving that error when dataList has been defined as private Collection dataList; and I'm passing in a Collection object.

To get this to not have an error I have to double cast it.

return (GenericListDTA) builder().dataList((Collection) dataList).total(dataList.size()).build();

Why do wont it recognize dataList as a Collection of DTO? Why is it defaulting to Collection

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example. Your code is missing the GenericListDTOBuilder.dataList method for example.

Answer (score 0):

Issue seems to be on the `GenericListDTOBuilder.data()` method. You are assigning parameter value instead of `data`.

```
public GenericListDTOBuilder<DTO> data(@NotNull Collection<DTO> data) {
   this.dataList = data;
   return this;
}
```

Comment: I'm not convinced this is the problem. The questioner is asking about a compiler error, whereas what you have pointed out would be a runtime problem. I suspect however that this is an artefact of code that hasn't been anonymised correctly: the code is inconsistent in its use of `data` and `dataList`, and `validUntil` is used but never defined in the class `GenericListDTOBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a problem with inferring the return type of `builder()` in your `just()` method.

There are two ways I can see to fix this. Firstly, extract the return value of `builder()` to a local variable, and then call methods on that:

```java
    GenericListDTOBuilder<DTO> builder = builder();
    return builder.dataList(dataList).total(dataList.size()).build();
```

Secondly, provide the type parameter when calling the `builder()` method. To get the type parameter in, you also need to qualify the static method with the class name:

```java
    return GenericListDTOBuilder.<DTO>builder().dataList(dataList).total(dataList.size()).build();
```

Note that the type variable `DTO` in your static `just` method is not the same as the type variable `DTO` in the class. You would be best off renaming this type variable to avoid any confusion.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4409195).